# Replace multiple variable values in a file with given input values (from a file)

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv-simple

If i have two input file with contents like below: How i can replace network_name  (eg:P1MSVmgmtvM replace with /rest/ethernet-networks/2bf8bc44-5b31-4e6c-99ed-d68b1e9acf9e).

File1: (input file)

```
Data_NetworkSet_A
 P1MSVmgmtvM
 P1MSVvMotion
Data_NetworkSet_B
 P2MSVmgmtvM
 P2MSVvMotion
Edge_NetworkSet_A
 E1MSVEDGEiDMZRUE1
 E1MSVEDGEiEXPRUE1
```

File 2: (with values for netowrk_name)

```
    "name": "P2MSVvMotion",
    "uri": "/rest/ethernet-networks/1d3188e4-9c06-4e92-92fd-dde4d6985151",
    "name": "P1MSVmgmtvM",
    "uri": "/rest/ethernet-networks/2bf8bc44-5b31-4e6c-99ed-d68b1e9acf9e",
    "name": "P2MSVmgmtvM",
    "uri": "/rest/ethernet-networks/8be8cdd2-e9a6-4ecd-9aa3-435e810c68e9",
    "name": "E1MSVEDGEiEXPRUE1",
    "uri": "/rest/ethernet-networks/97a47127-5c28-4c5b-891a-5ea3736306d3",
    "name": "P1MSVvMotion",
    "uri": "/rest/ethernet-networks/c16f119a-b556-464d-96dd-7fee9fd8dbc2",
    "name": "E1MSVEDGEiDMZRUE1",
    "uri": "/rest/ethernet-networks/cbb509aa-ab8a-4d85-886b-0899424f324c",
```

expected o/p:

```
Data_NetworkSet_A
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/2bf8bc44-5b31-4e6c-99ed-d68b1e9acf9e
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/c16f119a-b556-464d-96dd-7fee9fd8dbc2
Data_NetworkSet_B
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/8be8cdd2-e9a6-4ecd-9aa3-435e810c68e9
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/1d3188e4-9c06-4e92-92fd-dde4d6985151
Edge_NetworkSet_A
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/cbb509aa-ab8a-4d85-886b-0899424f324c
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/97a47127-5c28-4c5b-891a-5ea3736306d3
```

Comment: Do the files look exactly like that or are those just examples or parts of a file?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fields being quoted and split over two lines, this is a fairly standard lookup task for `awk`:

```
awk -F: '
function strip(x) {
  gsub(/[",]/,"",x)
  return x
}
  NR==FNR {
    i = strip($2)
    if (getline > -1) {
      a[i] = strip($2)
    }
    next
  } 
  $1 in a {
    $1 = " -"a[$1]
  } 1' file2 file1
```

giving

```
Data_NetworkSet_A
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/2bf8bc44-5b31-4e6c-99ed-d68b1e9acf9e
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/c16f119a-b556-464d-96dd-7fee9fd8dbc2
Data_NetworkSet_B
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/8be8cdd2-e9a6-4ecd-9aa3-435e810c68e9
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/1d3188e4-9c06-4e92-92fd-dde4d6985151
Edge_NetworkSet_A
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/cbb509aa-ab8a-4d85-886b-0899424f324c
 - /rest/ethernet-networks/97a47127-5c28-4c5b-891a-5ea3736306d3
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You convert file 1 so that the names become variable references:

   ```
   awk '$0 !~ /^ / { print; next; }; { sub("^ *","&$"); print; }' file1         
       Data_NetworkSet_A
        $P1MSVmgmtvM
        $P1MSVvMotion
        ...
   ```
2. You read the data from file 2 into shell variables (assuming no "dangerous" names (like `PATH`) occur):

   ```
    while read dummy varname; read dummy varvalue; do
        eval "export ${varname%,}=${varvalue%,}"
    done <file2
   ```
3. You have `envsubst` replace the names with the values:

   ```
    envsubst <file2
        Data_NetworkSet_A
         /rest/ethernet-networks/2bf8bc44-5b31-4e6c-99ed-d68b1e9acf9e
         /rest/ethernet-networks/c16f119a-b556-464d-96dd-7fee9fd8dbc2
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (all in one):

```
IFS=''    #prevent ending/trailing whitespace from being trimmed.
while read line in
do
        if [ ! "$(echo $line | grep -e'^\s')" ] # if the word is not begins from space
        then
                # just write it to result_file
                echo $line >> result_file
        else
                # cut leading space => grep in file_2 (get 1 line after match too) => grep for uri => cut no needed symbols => write it to result_file  
                echo " - $(grep -A1 $(echo "$line" | tr -d ' ') file_2 | grep uri | cut -d ':' -f2 | tr -d '", ')" >> result_file
        fi
done < file_1
```

This script reads from `file_1` and compare lines with `file_2`. Result pushed in `result_file`.